# Is there a way, I can get all groups from Meetup API without specifying query value in keywordSearch ? or using a regex

Tags: regex, graphql, keyword-search, meetup

Can I get all groups without specifying keyword or giving some regex to the Meetup Graph QL API ?
My objective is to get all groups for a particular lat, lon and radius. Here is my query:

```graphql
{
    keywordSearch(
        filter: {
            query: "/[a-zA-Z]/", 
            lat: -35.2809368,
            lon: 149.1300092,
            radius: 62,
            source: GROUPS
        }
        input: {
            first: 200
        }
    ) {
    count
    pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
    }
    edges {
        node {
            id
            result {
                ... on Group {
                    id
                    name
                    urlname
                    country
                    description
                    topicCategory {
                        id
                        name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried regex but it did not work.

Comment: Did you try `.*` as the regex? The regex provided in the query matches exactly one character.